# SQLMap host does not seem to be injectable, does this mean there are no vulnerabilities?

Tags: python, sql, penetration-testing, sqlmap, penetration-tools

```
python sqlmap.py -u "https://localhost:8080" --level=5 --risk=5

[15:13:30] [WARNING] parameter 'Host' does not seem to be injectable
[15:13:30] [CRITICAL] all tested parameters do not appear to be injectable
```

SQLMap outputted this after many testing rows, is this the normal behaviour of the program or did I enter the url incorrectly?

Image shows whole output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ... is this the normal behaviour of the program or did I enter the url incorrectly?

According to the output sqlmap did not find any vulnerable injection point.

Normally, `-u` would also require to specify parameters for testing, but since you've specified `--level` and `--risk`, sqlmap tried to inject into http headers with extended payload set. Some responses were suspected for vulnerability in `Host` header, but finding was not confirmed.